# Rendering ActionResult to string - comes out in incorrect order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an attempted solution at rendering an `ActionResult` to a string. I do this by passing in my own `HttpContext` which substitutes the Output text writer with my own `TextWriter`.

Here's the problem - the elements are rendering out of order. If I render the partial view by querying it directly through the browser, it works fine. If I render it through my substituted text writer, any @Html.Action elements within the razor view are rendered first, regardless of their position within the view.

So, here's my Razor view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<WebsitePresentationLayer.MgrScreenLayoutViewer>
@using  System.Web.Mvc.Html;

<div>
    @Model.DebugText
</div> 
@foreach (var item in @Model.Items)
{
    <div>@item.Title</div>
    @Html.Action(
                    "LayoutItem",
                    new
                    {
                        id = item.Id,
                        uniqueName = item.UniqueName
                    }
                  );

}
```

If I query the view directly via the browser, it renders in the correct order:

- @Model.DebugText
- Item1.Title
- Item1 Action Rendering
- Item2.Title
- Item2 Action Rendering

If I render this to my TextWriter, it renders in the following order:

- Item1 Action Rendering
- Item2 Action Rendering
- @Model.DebugText
- Item1.Title
- Item2.Title

Why?

Here's how I'm subsituting the Text writer. (I'm calling this from an ASP.NET WebForms page, so there is already an existing `HttpContext`)

```
public static class ActionResultExtensions
{
    internal class MyResponseWrapper : HttpResponseWrapper
    {
        private System.IO.TextWriter _textWriter;
        public MyResponseWrapper(HttpResponse wrappedResponse, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter)
            : base(wrappedResponse)
        {
            _textWriter = textWriter;
        }

        public override System.IO.TextWriter Output
        {
            get { return this._textWriter; }
            set { this._textWriter = value; }
        }
    }

    internal class MyHttpContextWrapper : HttpContextWrapper
    {
        private readonly System.IO.TextWriter _textWriter;
        public MyHttpContextWrapper(System.IO.TextWriter textWriter)
            : base(HttpContext.Current)
        {
            this._textWriter = textWriter;
        }

        public override HttpResponseBase Response
        {
            get
            {
                var httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                return new MyResponseWrapper(httpResponse, this._textWriter);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void Render(this System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult result, System.IO.TextWriter textWriter, System.Web.Routing.RouteData routeData, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase controllerBase)
    {
        var httpContextWrapper = new MyHttpContextWrapper(textWriter);
        result.ExecuteResult(new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(httpContextWrapper, routeData, controllerBase));
    }
}

public static class MvcUtils
{
    public static void RenderControllerAction<T>(Func<T, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult> f, System.IO.TextWriter writer) where T : System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, new()
    {
        var controller = new T();
        // We have to initialise the RouteData so that it knows the name of the controller
        // This is used to locate the view
        var typeName = controller.GetType().Name;
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(.*)Controller$");
        var match = regex.Match(typeName);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            typeName = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        var routeData = new System.Web.Routing.RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", typeName);

        var actionResult = f(controller);
        actionResult.Render(writer, routeData, controller);
    }
}
```

And then I finally output it to string using the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);

CMS.Website.MvcUtils.RenderControllerAction<PlayerGroupController>
(
   c => c.ScreenLayout(this.MgrPlayerGroupViewer.ScreenLayoutId),
   stringWriter
);
stringWriter.Flush();
var generatedString = sb.ToString();
```

---

I've written an interceptor for the `TextWriter`, and sure enough, it's receiving three calls to `Write(string)`

- Write(LayoutItem 1 action contents)
- Write(LayoutItem 2 action contents)
- Write(Model.DebugText and the two item titles)

Answer (score 3):

I went through this about 6 months ago. Goal was to use a partial to populate a jquery popup dialog.

The problem is the View Engine wants to Render them in it's own awkward order...

Try this. LMK if it needs clarification.

```
    public static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller thisController, string viewName, object model)
    {
        // assign the model of the controller from which this method was called to the instance of the passed controller (a new instance, by the way)
        thisController.ViewData.Model = model;

        // initialize a string builder
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            // find and load the view or partial view, pass it through the controller factory
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(thisController.ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(thisController.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, thisController.ViewData, thisController.TempData, sw);

            // render it
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            //return the razorized view/partial-view as a string
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to manually create my own ControllerContext, but this solves my particular problem. I still hope to work out why the ViewEngine is rendering in a strange order when I call ActionResult.ExecuteResult.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I remember struggling with this. At first I just tried to return a Partial and got nothing like what I wanted. I had to pass the Controller and "process" my View through it. Dove in head first all day once I decided on the direction. You seem to be doing something similar but coming from a slightly different direction. I have to dive in again to understand it.